# How to get default view when clicking on another label?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm new to jquery, know some basic stuff maybe a litle bit more. 
I working at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Islam_Ibakaev/jdqg6bsh/5/

```
$('label').click(function() {
 $(this)
 .find(':radio')
 .css('display','none')
 .prev()
 .css('display','inline-block');
});
```

Want to make it looking normal way. In other words, when clicking on other label previous label that were clicked must to get default view. 
Dont know how to achieve it. Will be glad to get some help information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow! Please make sure that you are aware about the [rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28679/the-rules-of-stack-overflow). If you find any of the answers good enough, please upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution is to just **remove** the jQuery. You can use CSS to achieve the same effect:

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eud6nm8/)

HTML:

```
<div><label><input type="radio" name="houses"><span></span>House</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="houses"><span></span>On shore</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="houses"><span></span>Rent</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="houses"><span></span>Trade and Service</label></div>
```

CSS:

```
label span {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

label input:checked + span {
    background-color: #49b956;
}

label {
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 13px;
}

input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
/*
$('label').click(function() {
 $(this)
 .find(':radio')
 .css('display','none')
 .prev()
 .css('display','inline-block');
});
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdqg6bsh/8/)**

You need to add `name` attribute to all radio buttons and same value for it (here I have it as `abc`).

In your jQuery, you need to reset the `display` to default and then apply the desired effect to `this` element (that was clicked).

**Equivalent Code Snippet:**

```js
$('label').click(function() {
    // reset all labels
    $('label')
    .find(':radio')
    .css('display','inline-block')
    .prev()
    .css('display','none');
    
    // apply effect to only 'this' element
    $(this)
    .find(':radio')
    .css('display','none')
    .prev()
    .css('display','inline-block');
});
```

```css
label span {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background-color: #49b956;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;      
}

label {
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label><span></span><input name="abc" type="radio">House</label></div>
<div><label><span></span><input name="abc" type="radio">On shore</label></div>
<div><label><span></span><input name="abc" type="radio">Rent</label></div>
<div><label><span></span><input name="abc" type="radio">Trade and Service</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "unselect" the input elements before making a new selection.
here's a fiddle with an update to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/charbz/jdqg6bsh/11/

```
function unselectAll() {
  $(document)
  .find('label span')
  .css('display','none');

  $(document)
  .find('label input')
  .prop('checked',false)
  .css('display','inline-block');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define your input radios with the same name like this

```
<div><label><span></span><input type="radio" name="radioname">House</label></div>
<div><label><span></span><input type="radio" name="radioname">On shore</label></div>
<div><label><span></span><input type="radio" name="radioname">Rent</label></div>
<div><label><span></span><input type="radio" name="radioname">Trade and Service</label></div>
```

in your js you can use this code

```
var radios = $('[type=radio]');
radios.each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){
        radios.filter(':not(:checked)').show().prev().hide();
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).hide()
            .prev()
             .css('display','inline-block');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have asked my brother. He encourage me with this solution which as simple as possible. The fiddle he has sent to me
http://jsfiddle.net/jdqg6bsh/12/

```
$('label').click(function(event){
    $('label').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

And this one http://jsfiddle.net/jdqg6bsh/10/ on pure css:

```
.circle{
    display: none;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: transparent;    
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .circle{
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}

label{
    display: block
}
```

Wish someone except me also find it helpful.